# Inject Apache Client in Quarkus RestClient

Tags: quarkus

I have the following problem, my current workplace uses SSL certificate authentication and some system redirect to a different one in order to validate/authenticate.

With the current resteasy client I cannot follow redirect and I've an SSL error of broken pipe, but if I configure Apache HTTP client in a proper way (allowing redirect and circular redirect) the connection works fine.
So my idea is to configure the http client and inject it as Producer in Quarkus Rest client.
Is it possible?

Thanks for any answer,
Mirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported. Please open an issue on the Quarkus Github issue tracker asking for this feature